# jQuery - make sticky footer stop at the top of footer and become sticky again on scroll up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that is sticky on every page, and I need it to stop being sticky when it reaches the top of the footer. I have this working properly, but I need it to become sticky again when scrolling back up the page. Anything glaringly wrong?

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
     var footerTopPos = $('#footer-wrapper').offset().top;
     var navBottomPos = $('#footer-form-wrapper').offset().top;
     if(navBottomPos >= footerTopPos) {
         $('#footer-form-wrapper').addClass('sticky');
     } else {
         $('#footer-form-wrapper').removeClass('sticky');
     } 
 });
```

To clarify, the first part works perfectly. The css changes from "fixed" to "absolute" and the form stays in place. The problem is, I want it to revert back to "fixed" when you start scrolling back up the page (my else statement). This part does nothing at all.

Here is a rough jsfiddle to show the issue http://jsfiddle.net/L693f5bg/14/

Comment: Could you please add your HTML and CSS?

Comment: Even better create a jsfiddle reproducing the issue.

Comment: Here is a rough jsfiddle to show the issue. Thanks! http://jsfiddle.net/L693f5bg/14/

Answer (score 0):

**--Edit--**

To keep what you have started with the same and not use any other plugins you have to make sure you are declaring the variable outside the scroll function so that it doesn't get changed every time you scroll and change its position.

```
 $(function () {
   var footerTopPos = $('#footer-form-wrapper').offset().top;
   $(window).scroll(function () {
     var windowTopPos = $(window).scrollTop();
     if (windowTopPos >= footerTopPos) {
         $('#footer-form-wrapper').css('position', 'absolute');
         $('#footer-form-wrapper').css('top', '0');
     } else {
         $('#footer-form-wrapper').css('position', 'fixed');
         $('#footer-form-wrapper').css('bottom', '0');
         $('#footer-form-wrapper').css('top', 'auto');
     }
   });
 });
```

Updated your [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/L693f5bg/26/)

Personally I recommend using [Waypoints.js](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/) and the sticky elements plugin. It does everything and it's super clean and easy to implement. include the jquery.waypoints.js and the sticky plugin then initialize using:

```
var sticky = new Waypoint.Sticky({
  element: $('#footer-wrapper')[0],
  offset: '90%',
  stuckClass: 'unstuck'
});
```

I updated the [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/L693f5bg/15/) using the Waypoints.js plugin

Comment: Thank you, and definitely a viable option. I am just really hoping to avoid any more unnecessary plugins on this site, and the only thing holding me back at this point is the ability to remove a class when scrolling up from the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thank you. I looked at the fiddle, and it does not appear to be working with the update you did. I may just have to go with waypoint as you recommended, but am definitely curious if you were able to get it working as you suggested above. I can't get it to work doing what you suggested. Thanks again.

Comment: The jsfiddle works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/L693f5bg/26/ not sure why it wouldn't work for you.